# Skipping acquire of configured file ‘multiverse/binary-arm64/Packages’ as repository ‘/mongodb-org/4.0 InRelease’ doesn’t support architecture arm64

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb, upgrade

I’m trying to upgrade Mongo from 3.6.6 to 5.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.6, running on an AWS EC2 instance.

I’ve gotten up until 4.2 -> 4.4, and am now using this tutorial:

https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.4/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

I’ve done the following command:

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list
```

Then, I ran `sudo apt-get update`. However, I get the following error:

```
Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository 
'https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 InRelease' doesn't support 
architecture 'arm64'
```

I can’t install mongo after this. I saw this:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-37692

which says there weren’t arm64 builds, but it got corrected? How should I proceed? Do I need to update my AWS instance? It seems weird that Mongo can’t be installed on Ubuntu…

Answer (score -1):

hello there i have problem this plz fix and send me Skipping acquire of configured file 'bionic/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://proget.makedeb.org prebuilt-mpr InRelease' doesn't have the component 'bionic' (component misspelt in sources.list?)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/531647)